# How to listen live sounds from input from external sound card?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, external-soundcard

I have an external sound card. It is connected to my laptop via USB and to piano via a `jack - jack` cable.

I can record sounds from piano (using Audacity) but I cannot hear the sounds in the live mode.

How can I enable live mode? How can I hear the sounds while I am playing piano?

---

I already tried:

```
gst-launch pulsesrc ! pulsesink
```

and

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

But none worked as expected...

Comment: @Sneetsher See [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/12433/2014/1/11) where we struggled to fix the problem... Unfortunately, no solution yet.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your problem is likely that the automatically picked source and/or sink for the loopback module is wrong. If you don't specify the source and sink when loading the module, e.g. with:

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1 source=1 sink=0
```

then the source and sink are picked automatically. To get the name of your sinks and sources you can use `pactl list sources` and `pactl list sinks`. From that output you can use in the above command the number id of the source, or its name, which can be something like `alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo`.

But the easier way is likely to just simply use

```
pactl load-module module-loopback latency_msec=1
```

and then launch `pavucontrol`, go to the *Recording* tab, change *Show: Applications* to *Show: All streams*. Now you can see from where the loopback module is recording, change it to the source from which your piano sound is coming. Then go to the *Playback* tab, and do similiarily and change the output of the loopback module to the sound sink where you would like to hear your piano.

Comment: I used `pactl list` commands to get sources and sinks and then I run `pactl ...` with `source=2` and `sink=1` - I still don't hear the sounds from piano. When some sounds were played on laptop they entered in an infinite cycle... :-) I unplugged the USB cable, quickly. The problem is that I can record sounds very clear from piano using the external audio card, but I cannot hear them live in headphones (that are connected to the external audio card).

Comment: The loopback works for me but about every 1.5 minutes there is a pause for about 1 second. I played with the buffer handling using the pulse audio daemon.conf but it doesn't fix the issue. Doing this increases the latency but the pauses don't go away.  Is there a separate way to increase the buffer size of JUST the loopback? is there a separate issue that I am encountering? Processor is not maxed, issue persists when computer is idle. Other audio such as through shairport-sync does not have the same issue so I think its the loopback command only that's impacted.