# High Latency when listening to Capture card using pulseaudio loopback

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, video-capture-card

I have a Nintendo Switch going through a capture card connected to my computer.

When recording gameplay using OBS, there is no discrepancy between the visuals and the audio. However, when attempting to actually listen to the gameplay directly through the use of pulseaudio's loopback module, there are several seconds (at least 5) of delay, rendering it worthless.

For setting the loopback up, I followed instructions as presented at
[How to listen live sounds from input from external sound card?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/403416/how-to-listen-live-sounds-from-input-from-external-sound-card)
, including the latency_msec=1 option, and I do hear the sound, just extremely delayed.

For troubleshooting this on my own, I have uninstalled and reinstalled pulseaudio, alsa-base, and pavucontrol and also purged them. I have restarted my computer.

Finally, I have seen the thread at
[PulseAudio Loopback Latency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/491825/pulseaudio-loopback-latency)
but was unable to use any of the suggestions to solve my problem. My version of GNOME seems to be different than what the suggested extension is available for (though perhaps it is possible to work around this).

Also I have seen some bug reports from like 2010 https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/566381 that seem related, but with no solution.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04. My mistake for not including that.